# How to combine a list of unequal lm object length into a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, plyr, linear-regression

I like to extract the coefficients and standard errors of each lm object and combine them into a data.frame with NA fill in for the missing predictors.

```
    set.seed(12345)
    x<-matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100,ncol=10)
    colnames(x)<-paste("x",1:10,sep="")
    df<-data.frame(y=rnorm(100),x)
    m1<-vector('list', 10)
    for ( i in 2:11){
    eqn <- as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(colnames(df)[2:i], collapse='+')))
    m1[[i-1]] <- lm(eqn, df)
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
cList <- lapply(m1, coef)
nms  <- names(cList[[11]])

cMat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cList, function(X) X[nms]))
cDF  <- as.data.frame(cMat); names(cDF) <- nms   # Pretty up the results

cDF[1:5, 1:6]
#   (Intercept)        x1          x2         x3         x4       x5
# 1  -0.2345084 0.2027485          NA         NA         NA       NA
# 2  -0.2334043 0.2074812 -0.05006297         NA         NA       NA
# 3  -0.2299977 0.2099620 -0.03892985 0.09777829         NA       NA
# 4  -0.2095798 0.2221179 -0.02710201 0.06403695 -0.1184191       NA
# 5  -0.2060406 0.2180674 -0.01062671 0.06632922 -0.1045128 0.130937
```

**Edit**:

To collect the standard errors into a similar structure, just do something like this:

```
seList <- lapply(m1, function(X)  coef(summary(X))[,2])
seMat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cList, function(X) X[nms]))
seDF  <- as.data.frame(cMat); names(seDF) <- nms
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  The standard errors and the names of the columns x2 to x10 are missing.

Comment: @Tony -- You're welcome. I've just now edited the answer to show how you can add column names and also collect the standard errors in a similar data.frame.

Comment: Great! the codes work well for extracting coefficients, but not quite right for extracting standard errors. I got the following message after seList "Error in object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: @Tony -- The problem was caused by the way you were assigning into `m1`. (The results of your first model fit were being put into `m1[2]`, leaving the value of `m1[1]` as `NULL`.) I took the liberty of editing your question to correct that (by assigning into `m1[i-1]` in the next-to-last line), and all of my code should now work without complaint.

Comment: Many thanks. You just re-indexed m1 1 to 10 rather than 2 to 11. It works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `merge` and `Reduce`:

```
m2 <- lapply(m1[-1], function(x) as.data.frame(coef(summary(x))) )

tmpfun <- function(x,y) {
    n <- as.character(nrow(y)-1)
    xn <- if( 'Row.names' %in% colnames(x) ) 1 else 0
    merge(x,y,by.x=xn, by.y=0, suffixes=c('',n), all=TRUE)
}

out <- Reduce(tmpfun, m2)
```

You may want to reorder the columns, or drop some of the columns in m2, or transpose the result.

Comment: This is quite compact. I have not yet come across to the use of Reduce, but will try to use it in the future- Thanks